# how to create partials or reusable page-components in ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic3

Please who knows how i can create partials or similar components in ionic 3. i have an app and it consist of 5 pages and on each page i have to repeat  tag. There should be a way i could just create one file, and place it there, then require or include it when it is needed just as in php, asp or other frameworks.

this is my code.

```
<!-- beginning of header....  -->

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>gallery</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openNotifications()">
        <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
        <span class="ncount">5</span>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>    
   </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>

 <!-- end of header ....  -->

 <ion-content padding class="body">
    <!-- this part changes for every page....  -->
 </ion-content>
```

So this is the issue, is there no way i could just save the entire header section as header-comp.htm and require or include it in every view that utilizes it. so i would have something like this.

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>gallery</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openNotifications()">
        <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
        <span class="ncount">5</span>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>    
   </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>

 <!-- end of header partial/Component ....  -->
```

and then in every page, i'd just import the header component and place the body there, for example,

```
import('header-comp.html');  //or include('header.html') or ~ something 

<ion-content padding class="body">
   <!-- this part changes for every page....  -->
</ion-content>
```

i know theres nothing like import here, afterall ionic is based on angular, and if anyone has crossed this bridge please i need your help now, and if there is a way, how can someone update a variable in the partial/component at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: If you add ion-header in app.html then its can achieve

Comment: the problem with using app.html is constraining the layout of the application, but if it exists as a seperate component then i'd be able to use it as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this including `ion-header` in app.html. I will provide some useful code which help you i think.

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>gallery</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openNotifications()">
        <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
        <span class="ncount">5</span>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>    
   </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>

<ion-menu [content]="content">
-----
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

Comment: i tried your method and it worked, but i found a way around it by creating a headercomponent and binding it to a template using a globalprovider, thanks for your contribution.